# Python 3, context based division

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find out if numbers divide cleanly by seeing if they divide into a float or an int, for example:

10/2 = 5
  10/3 = 3.333

The problem is, as I understand it, you can either use / and get ONLY float results or use // and get ONLY int results. I'm trying to figure out a way to see if some number n is prime.

The idea I had was to see if all numbers between 1 and n-1 divide into floats, as that would mean none of them divide cleanly.

This is an exercise gauging my ability for an introductory course, I realize there may be some library I can import but I'm supposed to solve this problem using methods that are at my level and importing libraries isn't.

So I was wondering if theres a way to use a divison which will return the true type of the answer, if such a question even makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see if a number "divides cleanly", you want to use the `%`<sup>1</sup> operator:

```
10 % 3  # 1
11 % 3  # 2
12 % 3  # 0
```

Clearly if `a` divides `b` "cleanly", then the result is of `b % a` is `0`.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Modulus operator</sup>

Comment: Here, 1 would be the remainder or modulus -- See: [modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: Oh I see, I can do an if statement for all numbers in a range and if it returns a 0 only for n/1 and n/n then that would mean its a prime!

Comment: @Samsara -- Yep.  There are much [better ways of finding primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes), but even your really simple algorithm can be improved -- only check up to `sqrt(n)`.  You don't need to check all the way to `n-1`.  (You can probably convince yourself of this if you think about it for a few minutes).